# Is it possible to write multiple statements in Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to read an HTML table into pandas and then print and also append the DataFrames to a list as well. Something like:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table))
[print(df),records_list.append(df), for df in dfs]
```

Comment: I would never use statements which have side-efffects, like `append` or `print`, in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, you would either need to expand it to a regular loop:

```
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
    records_list.append(df)
```

Or, you could even create a custom function where you would print and return:

```
def print_and_return(item): 
    print(item)
    return item

records_list = [print_and_return(df) for df in dfs]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but its not really pretty:

```
inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c']

mylist = [print(i) or i for i in inputs]

print(mylist)
```

This abuses the fact that the print function returns None all the time. The result is:

```
a
b
c
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

That being said, I would NOT recommend to do this and rather go with @alexce's answer.